# Why -I effect of SR2+ >NH3+

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronegativity

I have previously asked this question, but that was in a little ambiguous way.
So am re-asking the question precisely.

As electronegativity of N > S, hence the tendency of N to pull the electrons is supposed to be more than that of S.
Moreover there is two alkyl groups are attached to S (though I don't think alkyl groups will show +I effect as probably no scope for hyperconjugation!).
Then why is this contradictory trend?
[image]

Comment: I'm not personally convinced that this is a duplicate, but please hold on, a moderator will get back to you regarding this question some time soon. Jan's answer in the linked duplicate did argue that as N is more electronegative than S, NH3+ should be more electron-withdrawing than SMe2+. So, it is not exactly true that there is no comparison there. However, that does not automatically make your question invalid, since you are asking about why your textbook says the opposite.

Comment: I am also not at all convinced that this is a duplicate. However, you have asked [*the same* question before](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/74473/4945). Please do not do that. Instead edit the existing question with the relevant changes, making clear why it is not a duplicate. If you disagree with a close vote, you can discuss it on meta. Re-asking the same question will not help you. It is likely to be closed even faster, and many closed questions will trigger a ban.// I personally can't really follow your reasoning though. Please also include a citation for your screenshot.